# Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec

Tags: javascript, nginx, mime-types

I get the following error in my JavaScript application:

> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of “application/octet-stream”. Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

How can I get my scripts to run?

Answer (score -2):

In your nginx config file add the following line:

```
server {
    ...
    default_type application/javascript;
    ...
}
```